# How can I get the difference from two summary group in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 3 groups in Crystal Report. I need to get the difference between first group summary and second group summary.

These are the groups; the green color represents the both fields to get the difference, the red one the space that should be appear. And the yellow one the label that I already achieve put only in the 2nd summary.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VzCF.png)

The report is bound to a stored procedure, the columns distribution: rubro, Rubro; anhoanterior, Real 2020, anhoactual Presupuesto 2020 and tpRubro is the group criteria

[Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8im2S.png)

```
       line 1: 50
       line 2: 40
       line 3: 10
       group 2: 50     <- sum of the group

       line 1: 10
       line 2: 2
       line 3: 25
       group 2: 25     <- sum of the group
       difference 2: 25     <- difference of summary group 1 and group 2

       line 1: 10
       line 2: 2
       line 3: 25
       group 3: 25 <- sum of the group
```

Answer (score 0):

Field Explorer  - Insert Formula

You should see your sums under "Report Fields" and you can insert them into the formula to get the difference.